# excel Calculate value based on row and column number in table

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a table that has values at the top of columns and in the left margin of rows.

```
    9   10  11  12  13  14  15  16  17  18  19  20
3                                               
3.5                                             
4                                               
4.5                                             
5                                               
5.5                                             
6                                               
6.5                                             
7                                               
7.5                                             
8                                               
8.5                                             
9                                               
9.5                                             
10
```

I wish to calculate the value in a cell in the table depending on the column value and the row value that the cell corresponds to. The formula is

> 53 * (column value - row value)

How do I do that?

Comment: @pnuts but I'd like to apply that formula to the whole table. I tried applying it to the top left cell and dragging it over the table but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With *53* in O2,

```
=$o$2*(b$1-$a2)
```

Fill right and down.

[image]

Research *absolute* and *relative* cell references for more information.